# For-loop iterates weirdly

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

I am writing a section of the winner algorithm. This one does vertical wins for Connect 4, and yes, there are tons of redundancies and bad stuff, at least I think so, if you want to, let me know which lines are bad, and offer a suggestion, **place these in the comments section please.** BTW, is the label necessary? I have no idea. I threw it in there because I thought it might help.

I had an issue with a for-loop that runs part of the checker. So I decided to put in a print statement to see what was going on. This is what I got:

```
2 /////// 1
3 /////// 2
4 /////// 1
```

Note, that there are only three pieces on the board that are vertically arranged and have the same color. You can see the print statement structure below:

```
public String verticalWin(RoundButton[][] useArray){
    //int a = 1;
    for(int row = 5; row > 2; row--){
        for(int col = 0; col < 7; col++){
            if(nextTileExists(row - 1, col) && !useArray[row][col].getBackground().equals(Color.YELLOW))
                if(useArray[row][col].getBackground().equals(useArray[row - 1][col].getBackground())){
                    comeHereLabel:
                    for(int a = 1; a < 4; a++){//THIS LOOP
                        if(nextTileExists(row - a, col))
                            if(useArray[row - a][col].getBackground().equals(useArray[row][col].getBackground())){
                                pieceWin++;
                                System.out.println(pieceWin + " /////// " + a);
                                if(pieceWin == 4)
                                    if(useArray[row][col].getBackground().equals(Color.RED))
                                        return "red";
                                    else
                                        return "black";
                            }
                                else
                                    break comeHereLabel;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    return "A";
}
```

At the top of method, you can see I commented out `int a = 1;` If I un-comment that line, and go to the loop marked `//THIS LOOP` and change it to `for(; a < 4; a++)` The printed statements and operation of the code changes completely. What I get from the new printing is:

```
2 /////// 1
3 /////// 2
4 /////// 3
```

And now there are actually 4 pieces on the board. **What is causing this oddness?**

If you need more code or anything else say so.

Comment: Because that `for (int a = 1;...)` loop is inside two other `for` loops, it gets executed multiple times. The `int a = 1;` near the top of your code, that you commented out, sets the value of `a` to 1 **only once** for the complete execution of your method. Whereas, `for (int a = 1; ...)` sets `a` to 1 each time your inner `for` loop starts.

Comment: @JohnnyCoder What is your expected behavior?

Comment: When coding, it's best not to just *throw things in b/c you think they might help*. You should check documentation online and examples (there are lots of them) to understand how the constructs behave before you use them.

Comment: @lurker, I did, and felt that it might help, but I was not actually sure.

Comment: @CNomad, The expected behavior is the second print statment that I showed where the left side goes 2 3 4.

Comment: The `break` will break out of the inner-most loop that the `break` is within in this case. You only need the label if you want to make exception to that.

Comment: @lurker So where does this label transfer flow of control to? It should send it to the largest for loop with the row variable correct?

Comment: In a labeled `break`, the label would normally be before the start of the loop you want to break out of, and the break takes you out of the loop. It doesn't jump to the label.

Comment: But can anyone explain why the difference is so freaking drastic? With the `int a = 1;` inside the for loop condition, the code prints 2 pieces at a = 1, 3 pieces at a = 2, and 4 pieces at a = 1, why does this happen. None of the responses to this question answer the big question of why does the location of the `int a = 1;` affect this loop so wildly.

Comment: @lurker, that is what I was trying to achieve, to get out of the loop with the a condition, and move flow of control to the outermost loop that can be seen directly beneath the commented out line

Comment: I want to GO to the outermost, i think the label is unnecessary, and im getting rid of it. @lurker thanks mate

Comment: Sorry, I misread your prior comment about where you wanted to exit. Though It would be an excellent idea to get rid of the label entirely. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80443/discussion-between-johnny-coder-and-lurker).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly, strongly recommend splitting your program into functions. Since you are just learning and, let's face it, Connect Four doesn't require top-notch performance, I'd recommend:

```
public enum Result {
    kNone , kRed , kBlue
}
public RoundButton[] copyColumn ( RoundButton[][] board , int column )
{
    // return a new array with the items from the specified column
}
public RoundButton[] copyDiagonal ( RoundButton[][] board , int startRow,int startCol , int slope )
{
    // return a new array with items in the diagonal start at the specified location, either going up to the right or down to the right
}
public Result evaluate ( RoundButton[] array )
{
    // return whether or not any winners were found in this array
}
public Result evaluateBoard ( RoundButton[][] board )
{
    // Iterate through the columns & rows; if a winner is found: return it.
    for ( int row=0 ; row<6 ; ++row ) {
        Result r = evaluate ( board[row] ) ;
        if ( r != kNone ) return r ;
    }
    for ( int col=0 ; col<7 ; ++col ) {
        RoundButton[] column = copyColumn ( board , col ) ;
        Result r = evaluate ( column ) ;
        if ( r != kNone ) return r ;
    }

    // Iterate through the diagonals; if a winner is found: return it.
    // Assuming board[0][0] is the bottom left...
    // Only starting at rows [0,2] going up can have a winner
    for ( int row=0 ; row<=2 ; ++row ) {
        RoundButton[] diag = copyDiagonal ( board , row,0 , 1 ) ;
        Result r = evaluate ( diag ) ;
        if ( r != kNone ) return r ;
    }
    // Only starting at rows [3,5] going down can have a winner
    for ( int row=3 ; row<=5 ; ++row ) {
        RoundButton[] drag = copyDiagonal ( board , row,0 , -1 ) ;
        Result r = evaluate ( diag ) ;
        if ( r != kNone ) return r ;
    }
    // Only starting at cols [0,3] going up can have a winner
    // ... but we'll cover 0 in the rows section first
    for ( int col=1 ; col<=3 ; ++col ) {
        RoundButton[] drag = copyDiagonal ( board , 0,col , 1 ) ;
        Result r = evaluate ( diag ) ;
        if ( r != kNone ) return r ;
    }
    // Only starting at cols [0,3] going down can have a winner
    // ... but we'll cover 0 in the rows section first
    for ( int col=1 ; col<=3 ; ++col ) {
        RoundButton[] drag = copyDiagonal ( board , 5,col , -1 ) ;
        Result r = evaluate ( diag ) ;
        if ( r != kNone ) return r ;
    }

    return kNone ;
}
```

Comment: I do appreciate your answer, and I have broken it up. The method above only checks for verticals, as can be seen from the direction that the code looks for matching pieces. However, can you tell me why the placement of the `int a = 1;` affects the output so drastically?

Comment: For the exact reason others have said: when you define it in an inner loop, it gets sets every time. When you define it outside the loops and don't reset it, it doesn't get reset. That's a LOT of code for just checking verticals; its complexity almost inevitably leads to mistakes or confusion.

Comment: I know it is a lot of code. Im not a pro at algorithms, in fact this is the first one im writing, you should have seen this one's ancestor, the thing was longer and only worked 1 color....

Comment: @JohnnyCoder it might have to do with that "int a" doesn't reset during the whole function. In the first scenario, the break could've been called and exited the loop, resetting the "int a"

Comment: @CNomad, i figured out why it was operating strangely with the int a in the for loop, but I still cant figure out why it worked so well with it outside the entire looping construct

Comment: @JohnnyCoder If it worked well outside the loop (where you think it shouldn't be) but was "strange" inside the loop (where you think it should be), then you NEED to step back and re-think your algorithm.

Comment: @iAdjunct i figured it out entirely, I didnt take into consideration 2 things, 1. the outermost loop iterated resulting in a new running of loop in question, 2. i forgot to have pieceWin reset upon new iteration of the outermost loops. And I have a question, should I delete this question, or answer it myself and leave it as a testament to what happens if you dont think while programming?

Answer (score -1):

When a `for` loop starts, it executes its first clause if there is one.

```
for(int a = 1; a < 4; a++) {
}

for(; a < 10; a++) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

The first thing that this code outputs is `4`, since that will be the last value `a` will take after finishing the first loop.

```
for(a = 1; a < 20; a++) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

If you subsequently execute this, the first output will be `1`, since the value of `a` gets reset before iterating.

Comment: Wait, how does the first loop print 4? Variable `a` is a local variable, so the  a would not have preserved the value of 3, or at least it should not have correct?

Comment: The loop doesn't terminate until the condition fails and the condition doesn't fail until a is 4.

Comment: are you responding to my question about your first loop? If so, the loop terminates after a = 3... but should not hold that value because a is a local variable...

Comment: Yes.  The value of a when the loop terminates is 4.  I don't have a compiler to test with at the moment but I'm assuming a is local to the containing method.